# What is the best way to keep a file open to read/write?

Tags: javascript, node.js, io, fs

I have a local JSON file which I intent to read/write from a NodeJS electron app. I am not sure, but I believe that instead of using readFile() and writeFile(), I should get a FileHandle to avoid multiple open and close actions.
So I've tried to grab a FileHandle from fs.promises.open(), but the problem seems to be that I am unable to get a FileHandle from an existing file without truncate it and clear it to 0.

```js
const { resolve } = require('path');
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;

function init() {
  // Save table name
  this.path = resolve(__dirname, '..', 'data', `test.json`);

  // Create/Open the json file
  fsPromises
    .open(this.path, 'wx+')
    .then(fileHandle => {
      // Grab file handle if the file don't exists 
      // because of the flag 'wx+'
      this.fh = fileHandle;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      if (err.code === 'EEXIST') {
        // File exists
      }

    });
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? Are there better ways to do it?

---

Links: 
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_open_path_flags_mode
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the end?  You can't very easily modify JSON in place because it's a text format so if anything changes length, you have to rewrite everything after.  And, JSON isn't a format you can easily append more data to either.  And, on the reading side, you can't really just read a part of the JSON either. So, what are you really trying to accomplish in the end?  Are you just rewriting the whole JSON every once in a while?

Comment: If you want to regularly rewrite new JSON to the whole file, just call `fs.writeFile()` whenever you need to rewrite the file.  There's no meaingful reason to complicate matters by trying to keep the file open in between.

Comment: FYI, using the `x` flag ensures failure if the file already exists.  So, not sure why you're trying to use that flag?

Comment: I am trying to save user preferences of the application. I understand what you saying, being a JSON file I must always read, parse, change, stringfy them write to the file the whole thing again. If it was just sequencial data I could just append the data to the file end.

Comment: @jfriend00 Sorry, the r flag was a mistake

Comment: When you answer my other comments, we can better advise what flags you should actually be using.  But, mostly, I don't see why you're bothering.  JSON has to be read or written all at once so just use `fs.promises.readFile()` when you want to read it and `fs.promises.writeFile()` when you want to write it and don't over complicate things that don't need to be optimized further.

Comment: @jfriend00 I understand, so in that case the best option it is to use writeFile() and readFile(). I just thought that maybe there were a better way to do it. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Because JSON doesn't support incremental reading or writing (you basically have to read or write the entire thing), there's nothing meaningful to be gained by trying to maintain an open file.  You can't just read/write small pieces of the file.  If you JSON is huge and you want to update just a little bit of it, then you need a better storage format (probably a database) that lets you more efficiently update just a piece of it.

Answer (score 3):

Because JSON is a text format that has to be read or written all at once and can't be easily modified or added onto in place, you're going to have to read the whole file or write the whole file at once.

So, your simplest option will be to just use `fs.promises.readFile()` and `fs.promises.writeFile()` and let the library open the file, read/write it and close the file.  Opening and closing a file in a modern OS takes advantage of disk caching so if you're reopening a file you just previously opened not long ago, it's not going to be a slow operation.  Further, since nodejs performs these operations in secondary threads in libuv, it doesn't block the main thread of nodejs either so its generally not a performance issue for your server.

If you really wanted to open the file once and hold it open, you would open it for reading and writing using the `r+` flag as in:

```
const fileHandle = await fsPromises.open(this.path, 'r+');
```

Reading the whole file would be simple as the new fileHandle object has a `.readFile()` method.

```
 const text = await fileHandle.readFile({encoding 'utf8'});
```

For writing the whole file from an open filehandle, you would have to truncate the file, then write your bytes, then flush the write buffer to ensure the last bit of the data got to the disk and isn't sitting in a buffer.

```
await fileHandle.truncate(0);                         // clear previous contents
let {bytesWritten} = await fileHandle.write(mybuffer, 0, someLength, 0);   // write new data
assert(bytesWritten === someLength);
await fileHandle.sync();                              // flush buffering to disk
```